# KPIs Regional Metric Aggregation in Dashboard

Tags: sql, tableau-api, aggregation, kpi, regional

I have the following database structure:

**Servers** -       *A table with a list of Server Names*

**Server / State** - *A Join table resolving a many to                        many relationship among servers and states. One server could be linked to one or many States*.

**State -**         *A table containing a list of States*

**Region-**     *A table containing a list of Regions in the country, e.g. North, South, East, and West.*

**Country -**           *A table containing a list of countries.*

**My Goal**

I am trying to measure and report on server up time and view their metrics by State, Region, and Country using filters to display the desired dimension.

**The Challenge**

The problem that I am having is that since an individual servers could be linked or support many States within a Region or Regions, when looking at their performance metrics from a Region perspective, I get the aggregate value of that one server times the number of States. For example, if that server was up only 10% of the time and it supported 5 States within a Region, my dashboard shows the up time by that server for that region as 50% when in reality it should only show 10%.

**The Solution**

I am not sure if this could be solved in Tableau or this is an issue with the way I have my relationships setup in my database. **Could you please help!**

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the tables, and sample data and outputs.

Comment: Have you tried `Attribute`?